# how an ecdf object can be used inside an R package?

Tags: r, package, building, ecdf

I am trying to build an `R` package and it has several *ecdf* objects in it. They have been created by ecdf(some variables such as p1). I put them in a list and save that as *rda* file in data folder, however when I run the  function inside the package (suppose named b1) after installing the package I got the following error:

```
b1(zzz[1,]) (zzz is a data frame and I ran the function on one row of it)
Error in fc(p1) : could not find function ".approxfun"
```

fc is a ecdf function stored in the saved list, I called the list by data(list1), and then `fc<-list[[1]]`, inside the function.

I also did data(list1), and when I typed: `fc<-list1[[1]]`, I can see fc as an ecdf object, but when I type `fc(1)`, I got the following error:

```
Error in fc(1) : could not find function ".approxfun"
```

If I give the choice to R to choose fc as a function or data, when I used package.skeleton and put fc in mylist, it chooses as a function,  and creates fc.R, but it does not run, something like this will be saved in fc.R:

```
fc <-
structure(function (v) 
.approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f), class = c("ecdf", 
"stepfun", "function"), call = quote(ecdf(yyy$p1)))
```

however the object fc is:

```
Empirical CDF:    4825 unique values with summary <br/>
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. <br/>
0.01227 0.03857 0.05602 0.10730 0.15250 0.68020 <br/>
```

I really appreciate any help that I can get. Thank you very much for your time in advance.
I think I need to figure it out that how should I save fc for the building package. The stats library version is 3.0.1 (I thought that could be the reason, but do not know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the *R* versions are compatible here?
The internal parts of `ecdf()`  and `approxfun()` objects {yes, they *are* functions} have been changed relatively recently and now go via the `.approxfun(..)` wrapper which is a hidden in the "stats" namespace.

But I really assume the problem comes because you use  data(.) in order to use such objects in your package,
and on R package building, R may resave the data and ends up losing the important property
that  `environment(fc)` must have  `"stats"` as a parent environment.

```
> set.seed(7); Fn <- ecdf(rnorm(12))
> save(Fn, file="/tmp/Fn.rda")
> rm(Fn)
> load(file="/tmp/Fn.rda")
> Fn
Empirical CDF
Call: ecdf(rnorm(12))
  x[1:12] = -1.1968, -0.97067, -0.94728,  ..., 2.2872, 2.7168
> plot(Fn)
> Fn(1)
[1] 0.75
> q()

... restart R

> (load(file="/tmp/Fn.rda"))
[1] "Fn"
> Fn(1)
[1] 0.75

> parent.env(environment(Fn))
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So everything works with regular save()ing and load()ing  of ecdf objects.

Solution proposal:  Don't use `data()` for storing objects that are used inside your functions. 
`data()` is not at all thought for this (but rather for providing illuminating data sets).

Rather put it into something like  /inst/internal/ecdf_lst.rda
and get it into your function  by something like
`load(system.file("internal/ecdf_lst.rda", package="<pkg>"))`